# failing to bind string indexed query string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm attempting to bind some query string parameters that is indexed by string keys but i can't seem to be getting it to work

here are the values i was trying to bind

```
search[value]: Exception happ...
search[regex]: false
```

here is the model i'm trying to bind it with
    `getLogsAjax(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)`

```
public class DataTableAjaxPostModel
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public search search { get; set; }
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }
}

public class search
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }
}
```

the rest of the model is being bind correctly except for the search class object, i tripled check that the request contains values for that object, what am i missing here?
p.s. the same code was supposedly working pre .net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to bind each field manually. Using **reflection** will make it easily.
2. Aslo, there's no need bind those outer model's properties (`DataTableAjaxPostModel`'s properties) manually. That's because they will be done by the **built-in** model binder.

**Implementation**

create a custom binder `QueryStringDictSyntaxBinder<TModel>`:

```
internal class QueryStringDictSyntaxBinder<TModel> : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        try
        {
            var result = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
            foreach(var pi in typeof(TModel).GetProperties())
            {
                var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
                var qsFieldName = $"{modelName}[{pi.Name}]";
                var field= bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query[qsFieldName].FirstOrDefault();
                if(field != null){
                    pi.SetValue(result,field);
                }
                // do nothing if null , or add model binding failure messages if you like
            }
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And then decorate the `search` property with a `[ModelBinder(typeof(QueryStringDictSyntaxBinder<search>))]` :

```
public class DataTableAjaxPostModel
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List columns { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(typeof(QueryStringDictSyntaxBinder<search>))]
    public search search { get; set; }

    public List order { get; set; }
}
```

**Test Case:**

I test it with the following requests, and it works fine for me:

```
?draw=1&search[value]=abc&search[regex]=(.*)&
?draw=1&sEarCh[value]=opq&Search[regex]=([^123]*)&
?draw=1&seaRch[value]=rst&Search[regex]=(.*)&
?draw=1&Search[value]=abc&
?draw=1&
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more background of the code would be helpful such as the code section that is actually doing the binding however here is a dotnetcore controller example with query parameter binding. Also common practice in C# are class names and fields are both uppercase FYI.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult ExampleGet([FromQuery] DataTableAjaxPostModel dataTableAjaxPostModel)
    {
        // You should be able to debug and see the value here
        var result = dataTableAjaxPostModel.search;
        return Ok();
    }

    public class DataTableAjaxPostModel
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
        public search search { get; set; }
        public List<Order> order { get; set; }
    }

    public class search
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string regex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is literally nothing else related to this, the query object on the request with the keys exists and populated with their values, also, i turned the class names to lower case hoping it was the case sensitivity that confused the binder.

Answer (score 0):

seems like no one has an answer for this, so i took a different route and wrote my own custom binder, if a better answer came, ill accept it instead of this one, probably will refactor it later (hahaha IKR!)

```
public class DTModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        try
        {
            var result = new DataTableAjaxPostModel();
            if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Contains("draw"))
                result.draw = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("draw").FirstValue);
            if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Contains("search[value]") &&
                bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Contains("search[regex]"))
                result.search = new search()
                {
                    regex = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("search[regex]").FirstValue,
                    value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("search[value]").FirstValue
                };
            //...
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```